# No qualifying bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine' available

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I try to build simple Maven springMVC application. When I tried to deploy the application to my server below exception is thrown.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'viewResolver' defined in
>   com.phapp.configuration.WebConfiguration: Unsatisfied dependency
>   expressed through method 'viewResolver' parameter 0; nested exception
>   is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine'
>   available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire
>   candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

below is my maven thymeleaf dependency

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
        <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring4</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

my springmvc version is 4.3.7.RELEASE.

I verified my maven dependencies are included in my deployment assembly. 
I am using java configuration to create springmvc

*

```
@Configuration
public class PhAppDispatcherServlet extends AbstractAnnotationConfigDispatcherServletInitializer {
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getRootConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[] {RootConfig.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected Class<?>[] getServletConfigClasses() {
        return new Class<?>[]{WebConfiguration.class};
    }
    @Override
    protected String[] getServletMappings() {
        return new String[] {"/"};
    }
}
```

*

My rootconfig class

```
@Configuration
public class RootConfig { }
```

my Webconfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.phapp"},excludeFilters = {@Filter(type=FilterType.ANNOTATION,value = EnableWebMvc.class)})
public class WebConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver(SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine) {
        ThymeleafViewResolver thymeleaf = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        thymeleaf.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine);
        return thymeleaf;
    }

    @Bean 
    public TemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver){
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver);
        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    public TemplateResolver templateResolver(){
        TemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        return templateResolver;
    }
}
```

why the server could not find SpringTemplateEngine bean?

No qualifying bean of type 'org.thymeleaf.spring4.SpringTemplateEngine' available:

Comment: You have a `TemplateEngine` not a `SpringTemplateEngine` according to your methods.

Comment: Maybe you have 2 different versions of spring in classpath. Because 2.1.3.RELEASE provides spring 4.0.0.RELEASE and you manually add spring 4.3.7.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks M.Deinum.. When I changed my method to return SpringTemplateEngine it works.

Answer (score 0):

Because Spring looking for a bean with type `SpringTemplateEngine` or any other subtype. So you need to change return type in `public TemplateEngine templateEngine(TemplateResolver templateResolver)` to `SpringTemplateEngine` or it's subclass.